# How to pass date format?

Tags: php, date, format, twig

```
{{ post.publish_at.format(config_get('streams::datetime.date_format')) }}
```

That code above results into Thursday 30, June 2016. How to remove the thursday? How to pass a format?

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this to format date for more information about [date in twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html)

```
{{ post.published_at|date("j F, Y") }}
```

Comment: It shows the current date and not the date that the post is created.

Comment: @Kiko that means `published_at` is `null`, try dumping the var

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ post.publish_at.format("F jS, Y") }}
```